# Setup of CA authority and TLS across devices with Mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, tls1.2, mosquitto, ca

First post here so apologies if my etiquette isn't quite on point!

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how certificate authorities work between separate machines, specifically when it comes to MQTT and the mosquito broker.

I have generated my server and client certificates using [this link](https://github.com/tsi-software/Secure_ESP8266_MQTT_poc/tree/master/top-level-components/mqtt_server_setup#creating-the-mqtt-keys-and-certificates) and got them working absolutely fine on localhost. For the server, I used common name RPi-Host i.e. the hostname, and for the clients I used 'localhost'. An example of the code I use to generate a CA for a client is given below, where %NAME is just the name of the cert:

```
Generate Key with:
$ openssl genrsa -out <%NAME>.key 2048

Generate certificate request with:
$ openssl req -out <%NAME>.csr -key <%NAME>.key -new

Link to main CA:
$ openssl x509 -req -in <%NAME>.csr -CA ../ca/ca.crt -CAkey ../ca/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out <%NAME>.crt -days 365
```

Lets say I'd generated client and client2 certificates, I can then run the below in 2 different terminals on the RPi-Host, and connect no problem at all:

```
Subscribe to MQTT broker:
$ mosquitto_sub -p 8883 --cafile ca.crt --cert client2.crt --key client2.key -h localhost -t /world

Publish to MQTT broker:
$ mosquitto_pub -p 8883 --cafile ../ca/ca.crt --cert client.crt --key client.key -h localhost -m hello! -t /world
```

However, if I change the -h localhost to 192.168.0.190, i.e the IP address, I immediately get:

```
Error: A TLS Error occurred.
```

...which Isn't very helpful!

The aim is to try and connect to this from a separate machine, however I'm stumped just trying to do this on the same machine with its own IP address! Do I need to dome something fancy in the common name when generating the certificate? Sadly I have not yet sourced a tutorial which reviews connecting using mosquitto and TLS across 2 separate machines.

Any pointers appreciated, and terribly sorry if I'm missing the obvious!

Alex

Answer (score 1):

The hostname (or IP address<sup>*</sup>) that you use to connect to the remote machine MUST to match the CN/SAN value in the certificate presented by that machine.

`localhost` shouldn't really ever be used in certificates as it is just a placeholder which says "This machine". Using TLS/SSL with localhost doesn't do anything useful. You should always generate certificates with the externally used hostname of the broker.

If you can't set up proper hostnames in a DNS server then you should probably add suitable entries to the `/etc/hosts` file on all the client machines with the hostname for the broker.

The temporary workaround to the error is probably to add `-i` to the mosquitto_pub and mosquitto_sub command lines. This tells them to ignore any miss match between the hostname and the name in the certificate. But this is only a workaround as it basically negates one of TLS/SSL's two key features (1. proving the machine you are connecting to is the machine it claims to be, 2. enabling encryption of the messages passing back and forth between the client/broker)

<sup>*</sup> Using raw IP addresses for TLS is possible, but it adds another level of difficulty getting the entries in the certificates right.